# URI of an RDF resource in Jena model

Tags: java, uri, rdf, jena, ontology

While I create resources in the model and print the URI, I get the correct namespace. For instance, the URI is

```
http://www.somesite1.com/rdfdump/resources/resourceid-1
```

However, when I export the resources to an [RDF file (link to the file)](http://pastebin.ca/2679640) and I import it, I get the resource URI pointing to the physical location of the file in the disk such as

```
file:///D:/somefolder/resources/resourceid-1
```

I am using `com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model` in conjunction with `com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel`. The RDF model stores resources and I define an ontology using `OntModel`. Initialize them in the following way.

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, model);

NS = "http://www.somesite2.com/ontology"
BASE_URL = "http://www.somesite1.com/rdfdump/"
OntClass ocResource = ontModel.createClass(NS + "#RESOURCE");

//read an RDF file into the model
RDFDataMgr.read(model, file.toURI().toString());
```

This is the way I create a resource.

```
String uri = BASE_URL + "resources/resourceid-1";
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource rdfResource = model.createResource(uri, ocResource );
```

Can you kindly point to me where is that I am going wrong and why is it that I do no get the correct URI when I import the file?

One thing I noted is, if I have the same base URL for both Jena RDF Model and OntModel, i.e., say `http://www.somesite.com/...`, then I cannot retrieve resources in the model using

```
ocResource.listInstances()
```

It gives me 0 resources despite there being resources.

Comment: where's the code that writes the model to disk?  Also, please show (at least a sample of) the output in the question;  we need to see the data _here_ for the question to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RDF/XML document doesn't specify an `xml:base`, but uses relative URIs:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://www.someaddress2.com/ontology#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
  <!-- … -->
  <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A1">
    <!-- "tag/tag/…" is relative -->
    <rdf:_1 rdf:resource="tag/tag/rs_tagapplication-guid-5CCC6F83F6DDEE9DC69390E3767DEA4BD8BD4DCD4E9F3570A67E8F7455785C51"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Bag"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <!-- … -->
</rdf:RDF>
```

There's no `xml:base` in the document, so the relative URIs are apparently being resolved against 
the path of the file from which the model is being read.  Either (i) use only absolute URIs in your document or (ii) explicitly specify a base in the document or (iii) use one of the read methods that take a `base` argument, e.g., [read(model,uri,base,hintLang)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html#read%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.jena.riot.Lang%29).

Although you mention that you do:

```java
String uri = BASE_URL + "resources/resourceid-1";
Resource rdfResource = model.createResource(uri, ocResource );
```

I expect that *somewhere* you left out the `BASE_URL` prefix (and after all, you haven't shown us all your code) and did something like:

```
String uri = "resources/resourceid-1";
Resource rdfResource = model.createResource(uri, ocResource );
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had mistakenly was writing my model `writer.write(this.model, out, BASE_URL);` and the documentation says it relatives the path if a base uri is mentioned. But the base uri was never written into the model or at least it didn't take it into account when retrieving a resource.

Comment: Do you know why is that the OntModel and RDF Model need to have different base URIs? It does not work otherwise.

Comment: @user592748 I think the point of providing the base URI to the _writer_ function is to make relative URIs so that you can provide a (possibly different) base URI later on.  While it's legal to do that, it's typically much more convenient to ignore the fact that you can have a base URI, and to simply use absolute URIs everywhere.

Comment: @user592748 I'm not sure what you mean that "it does not work otherwise";  there's nothing in this question describing that problem.  If you can reproduce it though, it's a different question and should be asked a new question.  Models don't have base URIs;  some serializations of RDF graphs (e.g., RDF/XML, Turtle) do.  It's a property of the serialization, not of the model.  In light of that, I'm not sure what problem you're running into.  Also, I'm not quite clear why you're using a (plain) Model _and_ an OntModel.  I think you'll need to describe your setup a bit more in a new question.