# Jena showing wrong namespace for ontology classes

Tags: rdf, jena, rdfs

I have a local ontology with several classes, such as `User`:

```xml
<rdf:RDF 
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" 
     xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
     xmlns:domain="http://www.somedomain.com/data/#">

    <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="User"> 
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent" />
        <rdfs:comment> 
            The class of users.
        </rdfs:comment>  
    </rdfs:Class>

</rdf:RDF>
```

If I try to print all the classes like this:

```
/* Lists all classes */
ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classIterator = model.listClasses(); 
while (classIterator.hasNext()) { 
    OntClass ontClass = classIterator.next(); 
    System.out.println(ontClass.toString()); 
}
```

I get them with a local path:

```
file:///home/myusername/#User
```

Instead of

```
http://www.somedomain.com/data/#User
```

This is very annoying because my namespace in Jena is therefore `file:///home/myusername/#` and I do not believe this is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using relative URIs and they're getting resolved against the pathname of the file.  This is the same problem described in [URI of an RDF resource in Jena model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657447/uri-of-an-rdf-resource-in-jena-model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="User">
```

means resolve "User" against the base URI, which is file:///home/myusername/.  This is correct.

Either set the base URI to what you require in the model.read operation or you can give the URI: an XML entity useful: define the entity and in rdf:ID=".." and xmlns:domain=".."